# Can I use select as with select exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query, to use the result I have to do like $results[0][query], can I use select as or some other way to change the index of the results array?

```
"SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `records` WHERE title = '".title."' and id = ".$id.")";
```

edit: I know I could do it with php or even just not worry about it, but looking for a way to do it with mysql

Comment: Why do you need to change the index? BTW - you have some syntax errors here and I won't mention the possibility for SQL Injection Attacks. Oops.

Comment: Kind of dumb to use something so specific and unwieldy to deal with my variables, also instead of escaping everything we use a wrapper for mysql queries that escapes the variables.

Comment: When faced with any kind of problem, if one of the options is 'not  worry about it', that's the one to take.

Answer (score 0):

For building arrays, I would suggest leaving that to PHP.  Put your query results into PHP variables and build your array from there.

Comment: There's only one value I'm looking for and there should be a maximum of one, I am trying to check if the title of a record exists for the user.